# SSH in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

How to hardcode a remote server's password in my shell script ?As while using ssh command to connect to a remote server it prompts for the password, I am trying to automate the process so that it picks the password from my script. the ssh-keygen method did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding ssh password in a plain text is a bad practice. Better to use key authentication.
But if you still want to automate entering ssh password and not using keys, you can write small Expect script.
More info about Expect:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect